# Why is this condition not working? Div with class

Tags: perl, web-crawler

I have a condition where i want to retrieve text from a specific tag, but it does not seem to be returning true.. any help?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use HTML::TreeBuilder;
use warnings;
use strict;
my $URL = "http://prospectus.ulster.ac.uk/modules/index/index/selCampus/JN/selProgramme/2132/hModuleCode/COM137";
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($URL);  

if (my $div = $tree->look_down(_tag => "div ", class => "col col60 moduledetail")) {
 printf $div->as_text();
          print "test";
 open (FILE, '>mytest.txt');
 print FILE $div;
 close (FILE); 
}
      print $tree->look_down(_tag => "th", class => "moduleCode")->as_text();
 $tree->delete();
```

It is not getting into the if statement and the print outside the if statement is saying that there is an undefined value, but i know that it should be returning true because these tags do exist.

```
<th class="moduleCode">COM137<small>CRN: 33413</small></th>
```

thanks

Comment: @downvoter: what is wrong with this question?

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content` yet you are supplying a URL instead of content. You have to `get` the HTML before you can pass it to `HTML::TreeBuilder`.

Perhaps the simplest way is to use [LWP::Simple](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aSimple) which imports a subroutine called `get`. This will read the data at the URL and return it as a string.

The reason your conditional block is never executed is that you have a space in the tag name. You need `"div"` instead of `"div "`.

Also note the following:

- You shouldn't output a single string by using `printf` with that string as a format specifier. It may generate *missing argument* warnings and fail to output the string properly.
- You should ideally use lexical file handles and the three-argument form of `open`. You should also check the status of all `open` calls and respond accordingly.
- Your scalar variable `$div` is a blessed hash reference, so printing it as it is will output something like `HTML::Element=HASH(0xfffffff)`. You need to call its methods to extract the values you want to display

With these errors corrected your code looks like this, although I haven't formatted the output as I can't tell what you want.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TreeBuilder;
use LWP::Simple;

my $url = "http://prospectus.ulster.ac.uk/modules/index/index/selCampus/JN/selProgramme/2132/hModuleCode/COM137";
my $html = get $url;
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($html);  

if (my $div = $tree->look_down(_tag => "div", class => "col col60 moduledetail")) {
  print $div->as_text(), "\n";
  open my $fh, '>', 'mytest.txt' or die "Unable to open output file: $!";
  print $fh $div->as_text, "\n";
}

print $tree->look_down(_tag => "th", class => "moduleCode")->as_text, "\n";
```